# Converting reality to Petri net

Tags: modelling, petri-nets

I'm autistic and I think a bit differently. I have superior memory and visual thinking, but I have a problem with converting real thing to abstract. I'd like to model reality processes with Petri nets. But... when I think of cooking meal or using a coffee vendor machine, I see in my head vegetables, kitchen utensils, cooking books and coffee machines I have seen in my entire life, but no graphs.

I am able to draw for example binary counters, because their graphs look like real things. But I can't see Greek salad as a graph. I need some help. When I see the examples, I should learn it all very quickly, but now I have nothing to start and nobody to ask.

Comment: Petri nets serve well for modelling processes, so (naturally) modelling static objects is going to be weird. Find processes you associate with the given object and visualize these; in a sense, you'd "specify" an object by its interaction interface, not its properties.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure how to approach your particular problem, but here is an attempt.

Consider the recipe you are using as a collection of steps, some of which depend on others; for a salad you might have "make dressing", "shred lettuce", "slice cucumber" etc. The dependencies are given through resources, which here are ingredients, possibly in some processed state, like oil, vinegar, cucumber, *sliced* cucumber, etc.

To model this process as a Petri net, you use

- places to represent the various resources, i.e. you have a "vinegar" place, a "shredded lettuce" place, etc,
- tokens on those places to represent the amount of each resource you have; initially this would be something like one token on each unprocessed ingredient,
- transitions to model actual steps in the recipe; for example you could have a "make vinaigrette" transition consuming a token from the "oil" and "vinegar" places and producing a token in the "dressing" place.

The amount of detail here depends on what you want to do with the model; you might for example want to keep track of equipment in addition to ingredients (with the "make vinaigrette" transition additionally consuming a clean whisk and producing a used whisk), etc.

Is this the kind of example you had in mind?

Comment: Thank you a lot. I had a visual example in mind, because I learn with pictures.